# Giving money, gift, virtual currency to attract customers

Tags: sharia

As-salamu a'laykum, 
I am struggling a little financially. Now I am planning to do something, it involves getting people to sign up to win products for free, getting people to download software, etc. In order to get these people the companies allow me to use incentives like giving them money, offering gift, virtual currencies that can used for online shopping, etc in order to get these customers (these money or gift offered, I have to pay, I can make sure it's less than what they pay me).

Does this count as a bribe because what I think the companies are doing is trying attract customers for their business by giving them something in return so they can make more profit or more profit than competitors.

Please can someone answer this if they are knowledgeable in this field.

Comment: I don't have resources right now, but attracting customers is not haram, as far as you are not cheating on them.

Comment: jazakallhu khairan for the reply. I can hardly ever find a website where I can ask a scolar, some of them say that they have already reached maximum limit of they so can't take anymore questions.

Comment: @ShiuliBegum You can ask questionsonislam.com if you want. The answerers are Sunni (Hanafi) scholars.

Comment: What does this have to do with Islam? On the other hand, this sounds like a TERRIBLE decision. If you are already struggling financially, I wouldn't risk paying (random) people to do this. The reward certainly does not seem the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

No its not a bribe. Giving incentives for people to use a product is completely legit so long as their is no deception involved.

Comment: feel free to provide some support to your answer, it would be good than simply one line answers

Comment: Also references will make us happy !